# iOS UIWebView contenteditable autocorrect

Tags: ios, uiwebview, contenteditable

Currently it appears that setting **autocorrect** and **autocomplete** on a **contenteditable** div in mobile Safari is having no effect. Is there any way around this? Is it possible to set **autocorrectionType** on the UIWebView some how?
Thanks

Comment: I need this for my current project and I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this in HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, autocorrection will not work for uiwebview neither by objective-c code nor by HTML. Apple really sucks at uiwebview.